# Hadoop Snappy native library error with flume agents

Tags: java, hadoop, flume, snappy, bigdata

Hey I am getting an error with flume where it is using a snappy compression library and returning this error.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy()Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.checkNativeCodeLoaded(SnappyCodec.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.getCompressorType(SnappyCodec.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.getCompressor(CodecPool.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.getCompressor(CodecPool.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.init(SequenceFile.java:1273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$BlockCompressWriter.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:284)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:589)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSSequenceFile.open(HDFSSequenceFile.java:97)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSSequenceFile.open(HDFSSequenceFile.java:78)
    at com.mapquest.daas.flume.components.sink.s3.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:244)
    at com.mapquest.daas.flume.components.sink.s3.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:227)
    at com.mapquest.daas.flume.components.sink.s3.BucketWriter$9$1.run(BucketWriter.java:658)
    at org.apache.flume.auth.SimpleAuthenticator.execute(SimpleAuthenticator.java:50)
    at com.mapquest.daas.flume.components.sink.s3.BucketWriter$9.call(BucketWriter.java:655)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have tried all the other top google pages that have to do with similar issues.

i.e. create a core-site.xml, and mapred-site.xml

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>io.compression.codecs</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.output.compress</name>
  <value>true</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>mapred.map.output.compress.codec</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>mapreduce.admin.user.env</name>
  <value>LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/flume/plugins.d/hadoop/native</value>
 </property>

</configuration>
```

I have tried to add the snappy.so and hadoop.so files to the `.../jre/amd64/` path

I have also tried to specify the environment variables inside of the `flume-ng.sh` script that handles starting the jar.

```
export JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/flume/plugins.d/hadoop/native
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/flume/plugins.d/hadoop/native
export SPARK_YARN_USER_ENV="JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH,LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

I have also tried adding the snappy/ hadoop libs directly in the java command. this is a blurb from the flume-ng.sh script.

```
DAAS_NATIVE_LIBS="/opt/flume/plugins.d/hadoop/native/*:/opt/flume/plugins.d/snappy/native/*"

$EXEC $JAVA_HOME/bin/java $JAVA_OPTS $FLUME_JAVA_OPTS "${arr_java_props[@]}" -cp "$FLUME_CLASSPATH:$DAAS_FLUME_HOME" \
      -Djava.library.path=$DAAS_NATIVE_LIBS:$FLUME_JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH "$FLUME_APPLICATION_CLASS" $*
```

I am completley out of ideas on how to fix this. If anyone has any idea how to solve this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Hello, can you post the output of `hadoop checknative -a` command?